# If $ac=bc$ and $c \neq 0$ then $a=b$ using field axioms

Tags: real-analysis

If $ac=bc$ and $c \neq 0$ then $a=b$

Now $ac  + ((-b)c)  = bc + (-b)c$ . As $(-b)c = bc$.So,  $ac  + ((-b)c) = 0 $. So $(a + (-b))c =0$ . How do i proceed ? Thanks

Comment: $c$ has an inverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out in the above comment by The shark of Unknown, $c$ has an inverse and you can multiply both members of $ac=bc$ by $c^{-1}$, hence $a=b$.

Otherwise following your reasoning: you get $(a+(-b))c=0$. Since your are working with a field, in particular a domain; the product is zero if and only if at least one factor in zero. By assumption $c\neq0$, hence $a+(-b)=0$. Now sum $b$ to both members so that $a=b$.

Answer (score 0):

Lord shark's comment:

$c \not =0$ has an inverse $c^{-1}$.

Consider:

$(ac)c^{-1}= (bc)c^{-1}.$

Associative law:

$a(cc^{-1})=b(cc^{-1})$.

And now?